# How to add character variable in dplyr::filter?

Tags: r, string, dplyr, filter

I have a data.frame of species and I would like a function that give me a data.frame according to the type of habitat. The problem is that filter asks for "text" and not a variable.
And do you know how to name the created data-frame according to a variable ?
Have a nice day

Here is a part of the code :

```
table = data_frame(
  Habitat = c("Habitat1", "Habitat2"),
  Species = c("Sp1", "Sp2")
)

fct = function(habitat, tabl_habitat){
  table %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Habitat == habitat) ->
  tabl_habitat

fct("Habitat1", "Habitat1")  #does not work, neither one nor the other
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than having the function assign new objects in your environment, you could assign the function's output directly.

```r
fct = function(habitat){
  
  table %>% 
    dplyr::filter(Habitat == {{habitat}})
}
  
  
Habitat1 <- fct('Habitat1')
Habitat1
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   Habitat  Species
#>   <chr>    <chr>  
#> 1 Habitat1 Sp1
```